# How do I see all Protected questions?

Tags: support, protected

It seems like protected questions are usually really good. Is there a way to see them all?

I'm talking about a "protected" filter or some way to *only* see protected questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any way to find just protected posts. The search system has a bunch of special modifiers for finding questions with various attributes (such as being closed or even deleted) but nothing that I know of for protected posts.

That being said if there *was* such a feature I would submit a feature-request for its removal. Even as a moderator-only tool I cannot think of a good use-case scenario. Protected posts require no special attention—in fact usually the less attention they get the better. Such questions are not "usually really good", they are "usually borderline bad". The reason you are attracted to them is because they are often controversial and you enjoy stirring the pot. Frankly I'd just assume you were not enabled to do this.

Protected questions are usually protected because they have been a source of trouble at least once, but at the same time have been reviewed and let live (not closed). This probably means they have enough scope to be (and usually have been) answered but tend to be hot-button topics and controversy magnets and we don't want new users cutting their teeth on them. The less lime-light these questions get the better.